# How parse.com Local Datastore Work?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I know few thing about parse Local datastore link store objects in a local datastore on the Android device. Especially useful for temporarily storing data so that it can be synced later.

My Question is How Store data locally in android database and how synced later on when connect to internet. I think data store in android sqlite database temporary and later on when it connect to network data going to synced from cloud.

Is it right?

I want do store database on local database and when it connect to internet it synced. and if any update in cloud database then it synced in local DB. can parse useful for this or not? Please help me if someone know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use parse for this purpose. Start with this tutorial here. It gives you step by step procedure for the exact requirement as yours. https://www.parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore . Hope this helps.